# How to fix a Segmentation Fault in pthread_create call

Tags: c, pthreads

I am having an issue with my current code. I am working on a project where I am using threads to read a group of files from the terminal and tell how many lines there are in the individual and total grouping of files. My question is that when I run the code I get a core dump and when I run my code through gdb I get a segmentation fault at the pthread_create call. Is it because of my implementation or is it due to something else in my code?

```
#define NUM_THREADS 12
struct thread_data{
    char *thread_id;
    int count;
};

struct thread_data thread_data_array[NUM_THREADS];

void* filecount(void * thread_arg){
    char thread_id;
    int count;
    struct thread_data *thread;

    thread = (struct thread_data *) thread_arg;
    thread_id = *thread->thread_id;
    count = thread->count;

    FILE *fp = fopen(&thread_id, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s\n", thread_id);
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (char c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
        if (c == '\n')
            count++;

    fclose(fp);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if (argc == 1)
        return 0;

    pthread_t threads[argc];
    int t, total_count, count;
    total_count = 0;

    for(t=1; t<argc; t++){
        thread_data_array[t].thread_id = argv[t];
        thread_data_array[t].count = count;
        printf("Creating thread for file: %s",thread_data_array[t].thread_id);

        ///This is the line in question///
        pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL,filecount,(void *) &thread_data_array[t]);

        printf("File name: %s --- line count: %d", thread_data_array[t].thread_id, total_count);
        total_count += thread_data_array[t].count;
    }
    printf("Total line count: %d", total_count);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, you planning on joining those threads or just abandon them outright? Doing `total_count += thread_data_array[t].count` doesn't make much sense unless the thread `t` is done doing its job *first*. Also, if you actually provide 12 or more arguments on the command line you *will* breach your `thread_data_array` and invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: You have `FILE *fp = fopen(&thread_id, "r");` but `thread_id` is a single character.  You can't fit a file name in a single character; you need a null byte to terminate the string.  You don't need the local variable `thread_id`; simply pass `thread->thread_id` as the argument to `fopen()`.  Then we need to discuss your choice of variable and member names.

Comment: `thread_data_array[t].count = count;` makes no sense, since the code doesn't assign a value to `count` before that line.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help I have implemented what you said and made changes to what I needed to so thank you for your time. I hope you all have a great day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize some of the comments:

This

```
char thread_id;
thread_id = *thread->thread_id;
```

will give you the first character of the filename. So while `&thread_id` is the correct type (`char *`) for the first argument of `fopen`, its not a pointer to a null terminating string. This is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

In

```
thread_data_array[t].count = count;
```

`count` is uninitialized, and its value is indeterminate. This is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

You need to wait for each thread to finish before you use its result. [`pthread_join`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) is the function to use here.

`getc` ([`fgetc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html)) returns type `int`, which allows for the check against `EOF`. Narrowing to `char` removes the ability to properly test for `EOF`.

`thread_data_array` should match the `threads` array in size.

Here is a refactored program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct thread_data {
    char *thread_id;
    int count;
};

void *filecount(void *thread_arg){
    struct thread_data *arg = thread_arg;

    FILE *fp = fopen(arg->thread_id, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s\n", arg->thread_id);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    for (int c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
        if (c == '\n')
            arg->count++;

    fclose(fp);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc == 1)
        return 0;

    argv++;
    argc--;

    pthread_t threads[argc];
    struct thread_data thread_data_array[argc];
    int total_count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        thread_data_array[i].thread_id = argv[i];
        thread_data_array[i].count = 0;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, filecount,(void *) &thread_data_array[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        total_count += thread_data_array[i].count;
    }

    printf("Total line count: %d\n", total_count);
}
```

Comment: To be picky, you added a new vulnerability though, by moving `thread_data_array` from `.bss` to the stack. It may go out of scope in case main() finishes before the threads that use the data. Sure this is just an artificial example, but for production quality code consider heap allocation instead.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but it is rather picky, being design specific, and does not apply to this program. Here, there is still work to be done in main that relies on each thread finishing. The program does not work properly if a thread is unaccounted for. In this case, the number of threads and arguments are dynamic, and can not be declared with static storage duration. Using allocated storage duration opens up the question of where to deallocate. In the thread? `main` needs that data. In `main`? If `main` finishes before the threads, we have the same problem you described.

Comment: The generic advice should be to always ensure that the lifetime (not scope) of thread arguments at least matches the lifetime of the thread. Housekeeping is a matter of design.